# There is an alternative at source tag to deliver media base on screen size using CSS property background-image

Tags: html, css

I want to deliver the lighter image as possible for my website. To accomplish that, usually use source with that sort of HTML code :

```html
<picture>
    <source
      srcset="assets/images/compressed/litopia-s4-256.avif"
      media="(max-width: 512px)"
      type="image/avif"
    />
    <source
      srcset="assets/images/compressed/litopia-s4-512.avif"
      media="(max-width: 1024px)"
      type="image/avif"
    />
    <source
      srcset="assets/images/compressed/litopia-s4-1024.avif"
      media="(max-width: 2048px)"
      type="image/avif"
    />
    <!-- webp -->
    <source
      srcset="assets/images/compressed/litopia-s4-256.webp"
      media="(max-width: 512px)"
      type="image/webp"
    />
    <source
      srcset="assets/images/compressed/litopia-s4-512.webp"
      media="(max-width: 1024px)"
      type="image/webp"
    />
    <source
      srcset="assets/images/compressed/litopia-s4-1024.webp"
      media="(max-width: 2048px)"
      type="image/webp"
    />
    <!-- jpeg -->
    <source
      srcset="assets/images/compressed/litopia-s4-256.jpg"
      media="(max-width: 512px)"
      type="image/jpeg"
    />
    <source
      srcset="assets/images/compressed/litopia-s4-512.jpg"
      media="(max-width: 1024px)"
      type="image/jpeg"
    />
    <source
      srcset="assets/images/compressed/litopia-s4-1024.jpg"
      media="(max-width: 2048px)"
      type="image/jpeg"
    />
    <img src="/assets/images/litopia-port-s4.png" alt="Litopia Season 4">
</picture>
```

And I would like to know if there is something similar when I intend to deliver an image using `background-image` in CSS

like this :

```css
.bg-img{
  background-image: url("/assets/images/litopia-s4.png");
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries however you'll lack the format fallback.

Comment: @Kaiido yes but for example if the browser doesn't support AVIF how I can deliver the correct image?
Cause with source, also use type of file supported by browser to choose file to delivery.

Comment: For the format I don't think there is anything yet. The usual trick is to use something like modernizr, do the feature detection by JS and add a class on your <body>.

Comment: Okay so I can detect file format support and add class to the body like `avif-supported` and do somthing like that : `@media screen and (max-width: 512px){ body.avif-supported .bg-img{background-image: url("assets/images/compressed/litopia-s4-256.avif");}}`

Comment: Yes that's the idea.

Comment: Not ideal but I can do something with that, I will try ^^. However, if modernizr is too big compare to the gain of image size with avif I think I will just stay with webm that are supported everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do that with media queries :

```css
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .bg-img{
     background-image: url("/assets/images/litopia-s4-512.png");
     background-size:cover;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 512px) {
  .bg-img{
     background-image: url("/assets/images/litopia-s4-256.png");
     background-size:cover;
  }
}
```

Pay attention to the sequential order of Media Queries : it matters. (from the highest to lowest resolution)

### Edit

Didn't see @Kaiido comment before posting. But yeah, to check if your media format is handle, Modernizr would be the way to go I think.